# Detect the original and modified position of a marker after being dragged using the Control.Draw tool

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have the following scenario 
[Original position of the marker in leaflet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OItHt.png)

Then I drag the marker to another location 
[New postion of the marker in Leaflet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcI7b.png)

Then I drag the marker to another location introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

So I need the original position and the new marker position. I could only get the new position with the following method:

```
this.map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
    var layers = e.layers;
    layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
            layer.bindPopup(layer.getLatLng().toString()).openPopup();
        }
 }});
```

Comment: You could hook the `dragstart` event on the marker and save the pre-drag position.

Comment: unrelated but you could use leaflet.pm to edit your shapes and which gives you events after editing including the new coords. 
https://github.com/codeofsumit/leaflet.pm
Disclaimer: I'm the author of leaflet.pm